# Obj-c - Add NSDictionary to NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add an NSDictionary containing a series of keys to an existing NSMutableArray with the below code. However upon running the app, I get a crash on the very last line ( **[self.filtered addObject:nodeData];** ) that says: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and I'm not sure why?

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filtered;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {


 NSString *targetedUser = [self.messageDataFriends objectForKey:@"uid"];

NSString *universal = @"9506";

NSString *myID = [session user][@"user"][@"uid"];

 NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid ==[cd] %@", targetedUser];

 NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser ==[cd] %@", myID];

NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid ==[cd] %@", myID];

NSPredicate *p4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser ==[cd] %@", targetedUser];

NSPredicate *p5 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser ==[cd] %@", universal];


 NSCompoundPredicate *pIntermediary1 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2]];

 NSCompoundPredicate * pIntermediary2 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p3, p4]];

 NSCompoundPredicate * pIntermediary3 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p5]];

 NSCompoundPredicate *pFinal = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[pIntermediary1, pIntermediary2, pIntermediary3]];

                    _filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal];


    }


    - (IBAction)sendReply:(id)sender {


         NSMutableDictionary *nodeData = [NSMutableDictionary new];

            [nodeData setObject:@"messages" forKey:@"type"];


            NSDictionary *messageValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sentText, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
            NSDictionary *finalMessage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:messageValues] forKey:@"und"];

            [nodeData setObject:finalMessage forKey:@"body"];

                self.replyField.text = @"";

                NSString *targetedUser = [self.messageData objectForKey:@"uid"];


                NSDictionary *targetMessage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:targetedUser, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
                NSDictionary *finalUser = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:targetMessage] forKey:@"und"];

                [nodeData setObject:finalUser forKey:@"field_targetuser"];


            [nodeData setValue: @"Re:" forKey:@"title"];

                [self.filtered addObject:nodeData];

                NSLog(@"SHOW UPDATED FILTERED %@", self.filtered);

    }
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `filtered`?

Comment: See edit @vadian - clearer picture of what I'm doing :)

Comment: So, now the question is... where do you initialize `messages`?

Comment: @Alladinian Also in viewDidLoad. Though strangely, I just logged self.filtered inside my button method, and even that throws me the BAD EXC error. If I log messages inside the button method I get data as I should, but I'm trying to add nodeData to the filtered list :/

Comment: You can just put some breakpoints at the lines in question and make sure that your variables are what you expect them to be. You can also put an exception breakpoint to automatically pause on exceptions.

Comment: This could very simplified using array and dictionary literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this line

```
_filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal];
```

is the problem. You are accessing the ivar directly, avoiding the property setter to be called. This does not increase the retain count.
Replace with self.filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal];